# Why is the Remote Debugger Unable to Run?

Tags: asp.net, remote-debugging

Not able to run the application.

Get Error:

> The remote  Debugger was unable to locate a resource dll
>   (vsdebugeng.impl.resources.dll). please ensure that the complete
>   remote  debugger folder was copied or installed on the target
>   computer.

Comment: Please provide more context to your problem, and update the title in the form of a question which sums up the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I went ahead and updated the title based on the content.  OP, feel free to update if I've missed the point :)

Answer (score 0):

[As Stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-the-visual-studio-remote-debugger-service-on-the-target-computer-cannot-connect-back-to-this-computer?view=vs-2019)

**To correct this error**

- Make sure the Visual Studio Remote Debugger service is correctly set
  up on the remote computer. For more information, see Remote
  Debugging.
- Run the remote debugger service under an account that can access the
  debugger host computer, as shown in the previous table.

**To add "Log on as a service" privilege**

- On the Start menu, choose Control Panel.
- In Control Panel, choose Classic View, if necessary.
- Double-click Administrative Tools.
- In the Administrative Tools window, double-click Local Security
  Policy.
- In the Local Security Settings window, expand the Local Policies
  folder.
- Click User Rights Assignment.
- In the Policy column, double-click Log on as a service to view
  current local Group Policy assignments in the Log on as a service
  dialog box.
- To add new users, click the Add User or Group button.
- When you are finished adding users, click OK.

**To work around this error**

- Run the Remote Debugging Monitor as an application instead of a
  service.